# iPhone/iPod Touch Notes get synchronised to where?

Tags: sync, iphone, ipod-touch

I know with iPhone OS 3.0 the ability to synchronise notes back to a Mac or PC were added. I can see that the check box is enabled when my iPod Touch is connected. But where can I find the notes on my machine?

Comment: In your Outlook profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view them in Mail.app.  They are in the "Reminders" mailbox.

Comment: +1, that's right. Now, if only it was possible to to access the synced notes using some lightweight widget too, not only Mail.app... (Anyone else interested in that might want to keep an eye on this Macrumors thread I started: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=725091)

Comment: note that only Mac OS 10.5.7 and upper supports Notes syncing.